# No bounding box after custom traning YOLOv3 model

Tags: python, object, detection, yolo

[image]I have been trying to train YOLO v3 model for motorbike detection. The model trains well and reaches an average loss of 0.00001 in 1000 steps. But when I test it, I can see no bounding box or prediction.

motorbike dataset- 300 images

config file - tiny-yolo.cfg

classes - 1

filters - 30

```
#Traning
#batch=64
#subdivisions=8
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
max_batches = 2000
policy=steps
steps=-1,100,800,1600
scales=.1,10,.1,.1
```

I tried the following detection, it runs well but shows no prediction. Please tell me what changes should I make?